# Using Apportable with cocos2d-x

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, apportable

Does anyone have any details on porting a cocos2d-x project using Apportable? It doesn't seem to be as straight forward as porting a cocos2d-iphone project. I have been trying to trick it into thinking it's iOS by changing CCPlatformConfig.h to define CC_TARGET_PLATFORM as CC_PLATFORM_IOS even if the ANDROID flag is set. This doesn't really seem like the right approach to me but if anyone has successfully built a cocos2d-x project using Apportable any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Apportable cross-compiles Objective-C code to Android. Cocos2d-X is a C++ render engine and can already deploy to both iOS and Android natively. There is simply no need for using Apportable with cocos2d-x, and I wager they can't be made to work together in a meaningful way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combining incompatible technology.

Comment: I realise that cocos2d-x can already deploy to Android, I had just read of some people saying they had successfully used Apportable with a cocos2d-x project, apparently it has been done, I am just investigating it at the moment and trying to figure out how.

Comment: maybe they meant cocos2d-iphone, not -x?

Comment: I think down voting this so hard is a little unfair. It is pretty confusing right now, if you want cross platform cocos2d do you use cocos2d-iphone with apportable or cocos2d-x or um what where who?

Answer (score 2):

This is Collin here from Apportable.

[Hero Academy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.robotentertainment.heroacademy) is a cocos2d-x title that used Apportable for Android. You're on the right track, you should make sure that the iOS code paths are compiled and the Android ones aren't. We haven't been testing Apportable with each new release of cocos2d-x, so it's likely that there's some tweaking required to get it to work properly. If you get a cocos2d-x sample app working, let us know and we'll add it to docs.apportable.com!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tweaks to make the compilation work between apportable and cocos2d-x. You may find the instruction here http://blog.seanxiao.me/index.php/cocos2d-x-2-3-1-compiling-with-apportable/.

It is just a start but at least it passed the compilation. I will spend some more time working on the runtime issue.

Comment: you might outline the steps here, since the answer won't be useful if the link dies.